# Run a heavy PHP script that inserts data to Wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem running a PHP script that gets data from an external API that's returning image links and storing them as Wordpress posts using the `wp_insert_post()` method.

The problem is that the data is massive and the browser is crashing after running the script.

This is my script:

```
    <?php

$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://myapi.com/name');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);   


$objectCh = json_decode($result,true);


$ch2 = curl_init();


for($i=0;$i < 20;$i++){

    $url = 'https://www.myapi.com/api/images/'.$objectCh[chapters][$i][3].'/';







            curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL,$url );

            $result = curl_exec($ch2);

            $object = json_decode($result,true);



                    for($i=0;$i < count($object[images]);$i++){




                        $comic = array (
                            'post_content'=> "<img src=\""$object[images] 
                            [$i][1])">",
                            'post_title' => 'Chapeter 2 !!',
                            'post_status'           => 'publish',



                        );

                        wp_insert_post( $comic,true );
                      /*  echo ($object[images][$i][1]);

                        echo "<br>";*/

                        }




    }
    curl_close($ch2);
```

This is the script I figured out that runs the script many times and changes the script value, but still the browser is crashing. Is there any way to run this program without it crashing?

I'm using a shared hosting.

Comment: Doesn't fix your problem, but this `$objectCh[chapters][$i][3]` is probably throwing an error.  You probably want `["chapters"]` instead of `[chapters]`.  Aside from that, you could add in an [`ignore_user_abort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) so that the script keeps running even after the browser gives up.

Comment: no bro there is no problem the code is working when i'm echo the result for a small loop

Comment: If the script does not need to send data to the browser, then you might want to look into running it as a CLI script. This will eliminate the browser timeout issue.

Comment: Yes "bro", there _is_ a problem.  You should _not_ be using `[chapters]` like that.  Sure, the the script might still run, but that doesn't mean you're doing it right.  Like I said, changing that won't solve your problem, but it is something that you _should do_.

Comment: As Patrick Q mentioned, you shouldn't reference string keys of arrays without quotes around them. PHP will make it work but it throws a notice under the hood and thus affects performance. Next, this `"<img src=\""$object[images][$i][1])">"` should be that `'<img src="' . $object['images'][ $i ][1] . '>'`. Also, you are using $i to control the outer as well as the inner for loop.

Comment: yeah bro got it now thank you

Comment: Come to think of it - I think the core of your issue is that you are using `$i` to control the outer as well as the inner for loop.

This could potentially create an infinite loop as the inner for loop keeps resetting $i, preventing it from reaching the outer loops exit condition.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [generators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php). Something like this:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

final class PostWithImage
{
    /** @var string */
    private $chaptersUrlApi;
    /** @var string */
    private $imagesUrlApi;

    public function __construct(string $chaptersUrlApi, string $imagesUrlApi)
    {
        $this->chaptersUrlApi = $chaptersUrlApi;
        $this->imagesUrlApi = $imagesUrlApi;
    }

    public function generate(int $total): Generator
    {
        $chapters = $this->getChapters();

        for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
            $images = $this->getImagesPerChapter($chapters[$i][3]);

            foreach ($images as $image) {
                yield $this->makePostWithImage($image->current()[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    private function getChapters(): array
    {
        return $this->makeRequest($this->chaptersUrlApi)->current()['chapters'];
    }

    private function getImagesPerChapter(string $chapter): Generator
    {
        yield makeRequest(sprintf($this->imagesUrlApi, $chapter));
    }

    private function makeRequest(string $url): Generator
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        yield json_decode($result, true);
    }

    private function makePostWithImage(string $image): array
    {
        return [
            'post_content' => sprintf('<img src="%s">', $image),
            'post_title' => 'Chapeter 2 !!',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        ];
    }
}

// Usage:
$postWithImage = new PostWithImage(
    $chaptersUrlApi = 'https://myapi.com/name',
    $imagesUrlApi = 'https://www.myapi.com/api/images/%s/'
);

foreach ($postWithImage->generate(20) as $post) {
    wp_insert_post($post, true);
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code and describe how it is better than what OP has.  Simply dumping a bunch of code doesn't really help anyone in the long run.

Comment: Cannot use object of type Generator as array
in this line   $images = getImagesPerChapter($myApiResponse['chapters'][$i][3]);

Comment: I will do it. Give me some minutes

Comment: You can't assign the result of the yield operation like that - it gives it the Generator object instead. To get the value (so your array) do `$images = getImagesPerChapter($myApiResponse['chapters'][$i][3])->current();`

Comment: Yes, @Bananaapple I forgot to add that in the example.